# download html form + table as a xml/csv file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, html-table, forms

I am new to javascript, I need help with the following. I have a html file with a htmlform on top followed by a  table, that i filtered using checkboxes. I am trying to write a function to download the html form and the filtered values of table with header as one csv file or a xml file. Final goal is to have it as xml file, but if i can get a csv file, i can parse it and convert to a xml file. I tried following the discussion at [How to create and download an XML file on the fly using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143504/how-to-create-and-download-an-xml-file-on-the-fly-using-javascript) but it was not of much help.

html form looks like this

```
<html>
<form>
<fieldset>
Item ID:<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
Country:<input type="text" value="US">
<br>
Zip:
<div>
<label for="msg">Message:</label>
<textarea id="msg" name="user_text</textarea>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What you need to do is make a request to server with that data as the payload, then use the payload to write a file, then send back to client for download. However, without any more information there's not a lot anyone can help you.

Comment: I want to download entire web page after filtering as a xml file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to download a table in csv using only javascript, you should take a look at [datatables](https://datatables.net/). They have a very good library and have a extension to download the table as CSV and Excel all from the front end.

The extension is called Buttons you can find it [Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/).

Comment: I have a html-form on top of the table, even that needs to be downloaded along with the table in the same csv file. @vidal

Comment: How are you going to organize the form on the csv ? or how you want it ?

Comment: I want the form on top and then followed by the table. somehting like this @vidal

html form
...........
...........
..........
Table

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9